# Connecting the twitter api with native IOS

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to embed tweets into a tableView, which seem to can be done by using fabric. However i keep getting `bad request: 400` after i've followed the exact step-by-step guide. So far i've added the exact. Why do i still get this error?

Here is what i've done:

1. added the libraries and frameworks `TwitterKitResources.bundle`, `TwitterKit.Framework` and `TwitterCore.FrameWork`
2. added the `./Fabric.framework/run` run script
3. added this to appDelegate

   `Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("Consumer key", consumerSecret: "Consumer secret")
   Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])`

Added this below to my `TableViewController`.

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit


class TweetsViewController: UITableViewController, TWTRTweetViewDelegate {
    let tweetTableReuseIdentifier = "TweetCell"
    // Hold all the loaded Tweets
    var tweets: [TWTRTweet] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    let tweetIDs = ["603232039354114048"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Setup the table view


        self.title = "Tweets"
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f9f9f9")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#B52519")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f9f9f9")


        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // Explicitly set on iOS 8 if using automatic row height calculation
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.registerClass(TWTRTweetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tweetTableReuseIdentifier)

        // Load Tweets
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadTweetsWithIDs(tweetIDs) { tweets, error in


            if let ts = tweets as? [TWTRTweet] {
                self.tweets = ts
            } else {
                println("Failed to load tweets: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tweets.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tweetTableReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TWTRTweetTableViewCell
        cell.configureWithTweet(tweet)
        cell.tweetView.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]
        return TWTRTweetTableViewCell.heightForTweet(tweet, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds))
    }
}
```